# Proof of the convergence of infinite series of positive terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to prove the fact that the series of positive terms converges.

Precondition;

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is the series of positive terms, and
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

Problem;

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ converges.

I tried to prove that

> $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ is Cauchy sequence $\implies \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k)^2$ is Cauchy sequence.

However, I couldn't prove this.

How can I prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sum_{n=0}^∞ a_n $ is convergent, we have $a_n \to 0$ , hence there is $N$ such that $a_n <1$ for $n >N$. Then we have

$$0<a_n^2 < a_n$$

for $n>N.$ Can you proceed ?

Comment: I see. I appreciate your cooperation, It was very helpful. I will be able to proceed.